# Timertask stopping when screen locks

Tags: android, timertask

I'm using timer task to send updates on my API. The problem is, when the device is inactive, I don't really know the exact state. The timertask stops. Then when I unlock the screen and navigate again, the task started again.

Here's how I do it:

```
myTimer = new Timer();
UpdateCurrentLocation updateCurrentLocation= new UpdateCurrentLocation();
myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateCurrentLocation, 0, 900000);
```

This is updating every 15 minutes. But the activity stops when the device is disabled. I want updateCurrenLocation to be executed every 15 minutes even on background or the device is locked or even the app is not on the front.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You did not described what you are trying to achieve, but most likely you will have to create a `Service` or an `IntentService`, and make use of [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule the `Service` to be executed at every 15 minutes.

```
public static void scheduleSyncAlarm(Context context){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent syncData = new Intent(context, SyncDataService.class);

    PendingIntent pendingSyncData = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, syncData,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long syncInterval=AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR/4;

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0,
            syncInterval, pendingSyncData);

}
```

Comment: Any sample I could use?

Comment: addded a simple example.

Comment: Thanks! How should I set the alarm manager to fire the method that I need to execute? Thanks!

Comment: You can create just an `IntentService`... and the `handleIntent()` method will be executed.